# "num - 1" vs "num -= 1"

Tags: python

In line 4 why do we have to add "=" after "-" ?

```
num = 5
if num > 2:
    print(num)
    num -= 1
print(num)
```

Comment: No idea, print (4) print (3) would have been more succinct.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: this code is clearly illustrative.

Comment: Confused the heck out of me. num-=1 would have been illustrative. The question is utterly trivial, could have been answered with no real effort by the OP and the only reason I'm not closing it is just in case you lose your points.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: Confused ?? Have a look at the answers below :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`num - 1`: produce the result of subtracting one from `num`; `num` is not changed

`num -= 1`: subtract one from `num` and store that result (equivalent to `num = num - 1` when `num` is a number)

Note that you can use `num - 1` as an *expression* since it produces a result, e.g. `foo = num - 1`, or `print(num - 1)`, but you cannot use `num -= 1` as an expression in Python.

Answer (score 5):

```
num -= 1
```

is the same as

```
num = num - 1
```

Comment: Except when it's not, like `l += [0]` != `l = l + [0]`

Comment: Here it works, and you could write either `num = num - 1` or `num -= 1` because `num` is a number. But, if you had a list `l`, then `l += [0]` would not be the same as `l = l + [0]` (the former appends, the latter makes a brand-new list).

Comment: You're quite right of course. This is a very good point (although a little outside the question as it was asked).

Answer (score 5):

**The `=` is needed to assign the result of the subtraction back to `num`.**

The following:

```
num -= 1
```

subtracts one from `num` *and assigns the result back to `num`*.

On the other hand, the following:

```
num - 1
```

subtracts one from `num` *and discards the result*.

Answer (score 5):

Because `num - 1` does nothing, but `num -= 1` changes the value of `num` by minus one.

Answer (score 3):

You are essentially asking the difference between

```
num - 1
```

and

```
num -= 1
```

The former is an expression that evaluates to `num - 1`. The latter is an assignment that assigns `num - 1` to `num`.

So, the former does not modify `num`, the latter does.

Answer (score 3):

It's a shorter version of writing:

```
num = num - 1
```

Comment: Be very careful with that statement. `l = l + [0]` is not the same as `l += [0]`. `=` and `+=` are separate operators.

Answer (score 2):

You do not *have* to do anything, unless you are required to do something for your program to run correctly. Some things are good practice, but don't let anyone or anything but the compiler and the specification convince you that you *have* to do something one way or another. In this case, `n -= 1` is exactly the same as `n = n - 1`. Therefore, if you do not wish to put the `-` before the `=`, then don't. Use `n = n - 1` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`-=` is an operator.
This operator is equals to subtraction.

`num -= 1` means is  `num = num - 1`

It is used to subtraction from the itself with given value in right side.

Comment: This is Python. `num--` is not Python.

Comment: You said that instead of writing `num -= 1` you can write `num--`. And that's not the case in Python because there is no `--` operator in Python.

Comment: ok, actually I don't have the idea of python. I just seem that he is asking about num -= 1; and it is in other languages and I have the knowledge of c, java, php. where this is present, well thanks, I will remember it. And has change in answer.

Answer (score 1):

the `-=` is an operator, what you wrote will produce `num = num - 1`.